# How to make mockjax return an ember-data object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mockjax

Given that I have the Ember-data model (this is CoffeeScript):

`Person = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr("string")
  lastName: DS.attr("string")`

Or as JavaScript:

`Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr("string"),
  lastName: DS.attr("string")
});`

How can I use mockjax to return a Person object from the store? This mockjax doesn't work (I think) because it's returning an anonymous JavaScript object, not a Person object.

`$.mockjax
  type: "GET"
  url: "/people"
  data: { firstName: "John"}
  status: "200"
  dataType: "json"
  response: (d) ->
    person =
      {
        id: 2
        firstName: John
        lastName: Smith
      }
    @responseText = person`

Or as JavaScript:

`$.mockjax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/people",
  data: {
    firstName: "John"
  },
  status: "200",
  dataType: "json",
  response: function(d) {
    var person;
    person = {
      id: 2,
      firstName: John,
      lastName: Smith
    };
    return this.responseText = person;
  }
});`

I am using ES6 FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but instead of passing a variable to responseText, just pass it the whole object you are creating.

Like so:

```
$.mockjax
    type: "GET"
    url: "/people"
    data: { firstName: "John"}
    status: "200"
    dataType: "json"
    response: (d) ->
     @responseText = person: 
      [
       {
         id: 2
         firstName: John
         lastName: Smith
       }
      ]
```

Comment: Ahh I see. The type of object to be returned is person, then the list defines the properties of the objects to be returned.